# Callback on the function JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make this work, what am I doing wrong?

I want to be able to do some stuff when function `one` is completed.

```
function one() {
    // do stuff
}

function main() {

    //script
    //script
    one(function() {
      // do some stuff when "one" is completed
      console.log("one is completed");
    });

}
```

Why this doest fire a callback? (no log entry in the console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the callback as an argument and call it like normal function

```
function one(a, b, fn) {
    // do staff
    if (fn) {
      fn()
    }
}

function main() {

    //script
    //script
    one(5, 6, function() {
      // do some stuff when "one" is completed
      console.log("one is completed");
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, what if I do not need the callback every time I call this function?

Comment: Check my edit, you can just add a condition if the callback exist

Comment: Ok, I don't need to change anything in the 'main' func, this is correct? If I need to pass some parameter(s) to 'one' func, besides the callback, how do I do that?

Comment: Edited,, Because the callback is same as un argument you can just add arguments in the declaration before or after the callback

Comment: Thank you @Tristan De oliveira

Answer (score 0):

Cause `one` does not expect a callback, therefore it will be ignored and never called back.

```
function one(callback) { // <- take a callback
   callback(); // <- call back the callback "callback"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the callback function inside the one() function. Then you need to call that function:

```
const one = (cb) => {
    console.log('in one()');
    cb();
}

const main = () => {
    one(() => {
        console.log('one() is completed');
    });
} 

main();
```

OUTPUT:

```
in one()
one() is completed
```